# Counting records where a particular field is Null

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I have this code that looks in the [CanDate] field and tries to find all the records where it is Null. My problem is that I have 3 records that are Null but it's only finding 1. Can anyone suggest why that might be?

Here's my code

```vbs
Set rsCanCounter = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblGroupHeader Where CanDate IS NULL", dbOpenDynaset)
canCount = rsCanCounter.RecordCount
If canCount = 0 Then
    txtOpenAction.Value = 0
Else
    txtOpenAction.Value = canCount
End If
```

Comment: Add `rsCanCounter.MoveLast` after the `Set rsCanCounter ...` line. Does that give you a different `RecordCount`?

Comment: If you only need the count then `select count(*) from tblGroupHeader Where CanDate IS NULL` might be more useful

Comment: @HansUp You should post that as an answer.  "For recordsets based on queries, SQL statements, and attached tables, the RecordCount property returns the number of records accessed so far. When you first OpenRecordset(), Access grabs the first record, and keeps processing your code while the others load. So, if you test RecordCount immediately after you OpenRecordset, you typically get 0 (if there are no records), or 1 (if there are any, regardless of how many will load.) This does not apply to recordsets of type dbOpenTable type (the default for local tables.)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need a simple count, you might consider the `DCount` function...

```
CanCount = DCount("*", "tblGroupHeader", "CanDate IS Null")
```